# Spring data abstract entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

Я хочу создать базовый класс(AbstractEntity) для всех entity, в котором будет поле id. И столкнулся с проблемой.
Мне нужно использовать `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, но у всех entity должен быть свой `sequence`. Можно ли как то вынести это в базовый класс?

Если в AbstractEntity сделать вот так

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

то, если я правильно понял, у всех entity будет один генератор последовательности, а это не подходит

Можно ли как-то определить для каждой `entity` свой `sequence_generator` который будет использоваться, при этом оставив id в базовом классе?

В самой entity делаю вот так

```
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "users_sequence_generator",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
    parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "users_id_seq"),
            @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
            @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
    }
```

)

но остается вопрос, как "пробросить" это в AbstractEntity, что бы id который там описан, использовал именно эту последовательность?

Мне кажется, что это распространенный вопрос, но почему-то в гугле ответа на него я не нашел

Answer (score 0):

Укажите наименование генератора в базовой модели:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="users_sequence_generator")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

Аналогичные обсуждения в английской версии:

- [Specifying distinct sequence per table in Hibernate on subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560813/specifying-distinct-sequence-per-table-in-hibernate-on-subclasses)
- [MappedSuperclass - Change SequenceGenerator in Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589928/mappedsuperclass-change-sequencegenerator-in-subclass)

Comment: Да, я видел эти вопросы. Но здесь https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/SequenceGenerator говориться "The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit". И если я правильно понимаю, то в системе не должно быть генераторов с одинаковыми именами. Собственно hibernate такие варнинги и выкидывает в консоль

Comment: Хм. Ещё раз перечитав, нашел интересный момент. Есть настройка `hibernate.jpa.compliance.global_id_generators` и судя по всему, если поставить true, то генераторы будут глобальными, и будет падать эксепшен. А если false(по умолчанию), то они будут локальными, и это будет работать(судя по всему). Но в таком случае будут варнинги(не понятно зачем) которые сбивают с толку